# ¿Como hacer que una aplicacion de consola este siempre activa en c++?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Estoy haciendo un "process killer" y no se como hacer que al pulsar una tecla (F9 en este caso) se ejecute el codigo aunque este minimizado.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include "conio.h"
    #include "kill.h"

    using namespace std;

    int main(){

    loop:
char tecla;
tecla = getch();
    if(tecla==67) // 67=F9
        {
        killprocess("notepad.exe");
        }
        goto loop;

    }
```

El archivo "kill.h" tiene este codigo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <Tlhelp32.h>
#include <winbase.h>
#include <string.h>

void killprocess(const char *filename)
{
    HANDLE hSnapShot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPALL, NULL);
    PROCESSENTRY32 pEntry;
    pEntry.dwSize = sizeof (pEntry);
    BOOL hRes = Process32First(hSnapShot, &pEntry);
    while (hRes)
    {
        if (strcmp(pEntry.szExeFile, filename) == 0)
        {
            HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE, 0,
                                          (DWORD) pEntry.th32ProcessID);
            if (hProcess != NULL)
            {
                TerminateProcess(hProcess, 9);
                CloseHandle(hProcess);
            }
        }
        hRes = Process32Next(hSnapShot, &pEntry);
    }
    CloseHandle(hSnapShot);
}
```

Comment: parece que lo tu buscas es un hook al teclado para evitar estar ejecutando el bucle infinitamente.